# How do I hang a 200 pound chandelier?

Tags: light-fixture

I need to know how I should mount a 200 pound chandelier between ceiling I joists. Unfortunately, I do not have attic access.

Comment: Some additional info would be helpful. How far is it between the I-joists? What is the ceiling itself made out of? Are the I-joists wooden or steel? Please [edit] the answers into your post.

Comment: If I put a 200 pound load on 1-2 random ceiling joists, I would fully expect deflection and cracking of the ceiling drywall/plaster.  That weight should be spread across at least 4 joists preferably 6, which will require attic access.  If that's not practicable, then the fixture may not be a good fit for the house.  "First World Problems"

Comment: This shows how it is done, just check your nuts… https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=LFuYIi5-igc

Comment: Are you the owner of the building? If yes, then what has prevented you from accessing the attic?

Comment: Installing a 200-lb hanging load might require a plan from a structural engineer.

Comment: I would consider contacting the I-joist manufacturer to ask them about the proper way to attach a load across two of their joists. They may have very specific rules for doing so, and failure to follow their rules _could_ lead to a failure to receive payment on an insurance claim...

Answer (score 3):

You rip a big enough hole in the ceiling and put the required support in, then patch the hole (**ceiling roses**, which can be had in various sizes, some quite large, can be handy to make a nice finished cover over a more-basic patching job.)

Comment: I'm aware that I will make adequate opening my concern that I've been informed that the load of the chandelier must be supported to upper highest point of the I joist do you agree.

Comment: From what I recall of the extensive paperwork for my I-joists, glue-and-screw a web-filling board to the web (all the way from top to bottom) on both sides, then attach your support beam to the top of the joist and the web-fill with appropriate joist or beam hanger brackets.

Comment: What would you consider "the required support" for a 200lb load on two joists? "How do I build a bridge?" "Well, you put some pillars in the river, then build a road over it."